# Problem with OData routing / paths in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: .net-core, odata

I started working with OData and can not figure out how routing and paths are working.

Have a controller :

```
[Route("odata/[controller]")]
public class TestController : ODataController
{
    public TestController(IRepository<ETest> testContext)
    {
        _testContext = testContext;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery()]
    public IQueryable Get()
    {
        return _testContext.GetData();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery()]
    public async Task<ETtest> Get([FromQuery] DateTime key)
    {
        return await _testContext.Get(key);
    }

    private IRepository<Etest> _testContext { get; }
}
```

My problems are then I try access call controller with paths :

```
http://localhost:60286/odata/test?&key=2019-12-13T02:50:06.210553
http://localhost:60286/odata/test?$filter=mtts gt 2019-12-13T00:00:00Z&key=2019-12-13T02:50:06.210553
```

I have go an error :

```
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied..
```

How solve the problem with routing?

Is it possible to rename method Get to another name?

I looked into the resources :

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/experimenting-with-odata-in-asp-net-core-3-1/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/built-in-routing-conventions

Thanks for help.

Comment: It seems that miss filter parameter on get method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the second HttpGet to

```
 [HttpGet("{key}")]
```